# Access static property through static and non-static methods?

Tags: php, oop, static

I have a class and it has some static, some not static methods. It has a static property. I'm trying to access that property inside all of it's methods, I can't figure out the right syntax.

What I have is this:

```
class myClass {
    static public $mode = 'write';
    static public function getMode() {
        return myClass::$mode; 
    }
    public function getThisMode() {
        return $this->mode;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the actual syntax for this one?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For static properties use the following even inside a non static function

```
return self::$mode;
```

The reason for this is because the static propery exists whether an object has been instantiated or not. Therefore we are just using that same pre-existing property.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks. I'm a little curious why className::$mode doesn't work, though? I'll accept your question as soon as it let's me.

Comment: @DanRedux Cheers. Are you sure your first function does not return anything?

Comment: @DanRedux just checked your code and both work fine with my change of self. using myClass is just fine too.

Comment: if the class is extedned with a child class, then it is best to use static::$mode so the child class inherits the correct behaviour of the method

Answer (score 8):

If you are outside of the class, make sure not to forget the `$` or you will see this error as well. For example, make sure to call it like this:

```
$myClass = new myClass();

echo $myClass::$mode;
```

Not like this:

```
echo $myClass::mode;
```